# Use a before_filter to filter list of products based on location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I have a Deals Rails app showing the list of products on home page.

Deals have a deal_country attribute.

My goal: **I'd like to apply a before filter to filter the list of deals displayed to those whose deal.deal_country is the same as user's country (obtained through ip detection)**

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
   class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country,
     :only => [ :home]  


  def filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country
    visitor_country = request.location.country
    @deal = Deal.find_by(:deal_country => visitor_country)
  end        

  def home        

    @deals = Deal.featured_on_homepage.to_a # deals that are now active given their start date

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # home.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deals }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @deals }
      # format.atom
    end    
  end    

end
```

I am not getting any error but it's not "filtering"/displaying deals based on user's country. It does nothing different as if I had not put anything more than the before filters. method.

How can I do this?

EDIT

To be sure it's not working I have created deals that are taking place in the US with deal.deal_country= US". But in local, i am seen as being in FRance and I can still see it.
Note: I have put to have in local /dev mode my French ip by doing this (i am sure it'w sorking because when i put in the homepage view: <%= Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first.country %> it displays France)

in application_controller.rb

```
def lookup_ip_location
    if Rails.env.development?
      Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first
    else
      request.location
    end
  end
```

in config/envrionment/development.rb

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
  def remote_ip
    "84.34.156.155" # fake ip for example                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  end
end
```

models/deal.rb

```
scope :featured_on_hp,        lambda { default.where('date_launch_date <= ? AND date_end_date >= ?', Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now).where(featured: true) }
```

Comment: why do you have `before_filter :filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country!` and then you have defined this filter as def filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country end?

Comment: How is this both a RoR3 and RoR4 question?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `!` in `def filter_deals_based_on_visitor_country`, so its not getting called.

even if you correct this mistake, you will get an error in this line

```
@deal = Deal(:deal_country => visitor_country)
```

the correct syntax is

```
@deal = Deal.find_by(:deal_country => visitor_country)
```

Comment: I did what you say and actually (changed some code too) but the list i ma getting is still not the right one? see EDIT